# In the integrated debugger is there an implicit variable for exceptions

Tags: delphi, debugging

I would like to examine the exception in the debugger.

When I have

```
except on e:exception do
```

This is trivial, I can just examine the e variable

But, many exception handlers do not have an *on e:exception* clause.

Is there a special variable such as $exception that can be inspected, or some other method to inspect the exception that does not require changing the source.

I remember doing this (though memory can be faulty), but have not been able find a way to do this.

Comment: If the exception doesn't have a handler (the except block is empty), then the exception is being discarded. Why would you need to inspect the exception object when your code has determined (apparently incorrectly) that it should discard the exception?

Comment: @KenWhite Because whilst the code might not need to inspect the exception, the person debugging might well want to do so.

Comment: @KenWhite - in my case, I had an intermittent error that was difficult to reproduce, and I really wished I could have remembered how to do this since it would not fail after changing the source and recompiling - so I am definitely adding the answer to my bag of tricks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the `System` unit there is a function named [`ExceptObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ExceptObject) which returns the exception object that is currently active, or `nil` if no exception is active. The debugger is able to evaluate this function and so give you the information you need.

Comment: In order to get more useful information in the debugger you may have to cast the result of the function to Exception, as its return value is a TObject. Thus in yoiur debugger: ''Exception(ExceptObject)'' - and don't forget to enable function calls in the watch settings.